# Keeping that evil cursor from running off

Tags: evil

In Evil, as in Vim, combining an operation with a movement moves the cursor to the beginning of the text operated on.  For example, if I'm in the middle of a line and type `gU^`, then everything from the cursor to the beginning of the current line is upcased; but the cursor is also moved to the beginning of the line.  I would like it better if in general the cursor did not move.  Can this be achieved?